# cURL doesn't work on WAMP

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

I'm playing with NXT API and I need cURL to send/recieve POST forms. Problems starts just at the beginning when I'm calling the fucntion

```
$handler = curl_init();
```

WAMP returns me the following message: "Call to undefined function curl_init()".

I enabled the curl extension in WAMP menu. I tried too to uncomment the line extension=php_curl.dll from the files php.ini, php.ini-development and php.ini-production. I also tried to download the cURL library from http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-&ver=- , unzip the file and move the curl.exe to the folder C:/windows/system32. It stills not working and I don't know what else I can try...

PS: Im working with PHP 5.4.3 and Apache 2.4.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run phpinfo, so you see curl listed?

Comment: create a php file called info.php and put <?php phpinfo();?>. save the file and run info.php. do you see anything about curl in there? or search the entire document for the curl.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you downloaded from curl.haxx.se was the curl command line processor, and you dont need that to get php_curl working.

Can I suggest you try downloading the 64bit VC9 php_curl.dll 
[from here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) click the link -

*PHP 5.3.8 x64 (64 Bit) for Windows* and download the zip.

Unzip that file and replace \wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_curl.dll with the file from the zip.

For some reason the 64bit curl delivered with some version of 64bit php does not work very well but this version does.

To be honest, you would be better off using 32bit WAMPServer for this and other reasons, not least of which being that 64bit PHP at least on Windows is not a full 64bit port yet, and is considered *Experimental* even on the PHP web site. But that said this downloaded DLL should solver your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Stop WAMP
2. Edit C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.XX\php.ini (X.X.XX = php version)
3. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
4. Edit C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.X.X\bin\php.ini (X.X.X = php version)
5. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
6. Save files
7. Start WAMP